# pycharm not suspend when calling a function from debugger console

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, breakpoints

Suppose I have the following python code:

```
import dummy

def run():
    print('Running calc() function')
    y = dummy.perform_very_long_calculation()
    out = calc(y) #BP1 is here
    print(out)

def calc(x):
    print('Calculating ...')
    return x+2 #BP2 is here

run()
```

The goal is to have this flow:

1. Put a debug break-point ("BP1") on "out = calc(y)" line.
2. Put a debug break-point ("BP2") on "return x+2" line.
3. Run the module and stop on this "BP1".
4. Call calc(y) from the interactive debug console.
5. Stop on "BP2".
6. debug calc()
7. goto #4 and repeat, until I am pleased with calc()

The problem:
item 5 is **not working**. The code is not suspended on "BP2".

My motivation:
I want to call calc function until it is good.
This way I can dubug calc again and again without calling it through run which take 20 seconds.
I am very used to this kind of debugging flow from Matlab IDE and it is very convenience.

**How can I make "BP2" stop?**

Comment: There must be something else going on that you're missing. Because if you set those breakpoints and just step through the code it will stop at that `return`. FWIW, I can't replicate this with your code.

Comment: Thanks idjaw. I am not talking about stepping to "BP2" (this is working) but to call it from the debug console while i am suspended on "BL1"