# any Python IDE supports stopping in breakpoint from the debugger

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, pydev, breakpoints

I am looking for the following (IMHO, very important) feature:

1. Suppose I have two functions fa() and fb(), both of them has a breakpoint.
2. I am now stopped in the breakpoint in fa function.
3. In the interactive debugger console I am calling fb().

**I want to stop in fb breakpoint, but, unfortunately pb() runs but ignores the breakpoint.**
someone in another SO thread called it "nested breakpoints".

I am a developer that come from Matlab, in Matlab no matter how a function is called, from console, from debugger. if it has a breakpoint it stops.

I read past threads about this subject and did not find any solution.
I also tried latest pycharm community and latest pydev and no luck.
I also read that visual studio can not make it.

**Is this inherent in Python and technically can not be done?**

**Is there a technique / another IDE that supports it?**

Comment: If it is for windows, I would suggest Visual Studio. It has whole lot of features Breakpoints, immediate window, etc.,

Comment: but it does not have the feature I want

Comment: To my knowledge the best IDE for Python is Visual Studio and Wing IDE for Python see here https://wingware.com/doc/debug/setting-breakpoints

Comment: test wing ide and what i need does not work.
Calling a function with breakpoint from the "debug probe" does not stop on the breakpoint. 
As for VS, It does not support this feature either.

Answer (score 2):

I followed this question and saw nobody is answering, I thought about this feature too so I started digging through google <sup><sup>[and found your old question :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36693551/pycharm-not-suspend-when-calling-a-function-from-debugger-console)</sup></sup>

### TL;DR - You can't do that

(I tried with PyCharm, Visual-Studio and Eric Python IDE).

My guess that not working because it adds more complexity to debugging - what happened when you step to the next line? and if you have many threads/processes? what happens to mutable types?

### My way to do it

If you have 2 functions and you want to debug both of them:

```
def parent():
    dummy_debuggable_var = 1
    print('Running child() function')
    out = child(dummy_debuggable_var) #BP1 is here
    print(out)

def child(x):
    print('Calculating ...')
    return x+2
```

And your goal is to debug the `dummy_debuggable_var` and also the `child` function:

1. Put the break point where is comment is
2. Run the script
3. When the break point stops, inspect your `dummy_debuggable_var`
4. `step-into` (on PyCharm - <kbd>F7</kbd>)
5. Inspect your `child` function

While you're inside the `child` function, you can look on your PyCharm's frames stack tab on your [debugger window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debug-tool-window.html), this will let you jump back to the `parent`'s frame and inspect it.

This is more sequential process, and not parallel, but it's simple and it works.

Comment: thanks @or. I am aware on the technique you suggested, but this still not what I am looking for. 
Think that "child" is another module. I want to break on parent's #BP1, call child from console (not f7). stop on child. inspect. edit and fix. call again from console. inspec. fix ... until child is good. this way I can edit child module in the context of his parent caller parameter. now what I can do is either run both of them every time (long ...) or save the parameters and context and load them in child (... code change and not elegant).

Comment: That the exact same as step into child, get to the last line, make your changes, and then continue back to the parent function, or am I missing something?

Comment: After you get back to parent. how do you run child again? and if still not good how do you stop on a child breakpoint for fixing again?

Comment: You don't run it again, the whole point is to make your modifications on the last line of `child` on run-time with the debugger, so the child will return your expected value. This is equivalent to rerun your child, but from a different approach.

Comment: My purpose is not to fix the expected value but to actually continue building the function, until it is doing what i need it to do,

Comment: I also opened a feature request on pdev debugger (pydev and pycharm using it) https://github.com/fabioz/PyDev.Debugger/issues/98

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at Eric Python IDE and VSC(Visual Studio Code)

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mension PyCharm. It has also a powerful Debugger.

Comment: I tested pycharm and as I stated in the original post, the feature I am looking for "nested breakpoint" is not working. 
do you know if it exists in Eric Python and VSC.?

Comment: None of those IDE allows to stop at breakpoint in functions called from command line.

Comment: Thanks @sergey. Do you think/know if this is a language limitation?